# jQuery .change DRY code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

I have the put together checkboxes using '[bootstraptoggle](https://github.com/minhur/bootstrap-toggle)' plugin. I am building a mongoDB query based on the boxes checked.

**The code works flawlessly but I hate repeating the .change, is there any way to make this DRY?**

I have the following code

HTML

```
<div id="checkBoxContainer" class="container">
     <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="optionOne" data-onstyle="success" data- offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle">
     </label>
     <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="optionTwo" data-onstyle="success" data- offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle">
     </label>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#optionOne').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        queryBuilder.push($(this).attr("id"));
    } else if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
        queryBuilder.splice($(this).attr("id"));
    }
    console.log(queryBuilder);
});


$('#optionTwo').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        queryBuilder.push($(this).attr("id"));
    } else if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
        queryBuilder.splice($(this).attr("id"));
    }
    console.log(queryBuilder);
});
```

**I have searched and tried the following but no luck.**

```
$('document').on('change','#checkBoxContainer', function() {    
      if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        queryBuilder.push($(this).attr("id"));
    } else if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
        queryBuilder.splice($(this).attr("id"));
    }
    console.log(queryBuilder);

});
```

Comment: this is better suited on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: A couple off-topic tips... use `this.id` and `this.checked` instead of `$(this).attr("id")` and `$(this).prop("checked")`. Shorter and faster that way. Don't need all that jQuery.

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeStocker for your feedback, shall I delete and repost there?

Comment: @Rkhayat: It's too late after there's an answer with votes. Just as a rule of thumb, if you have fully working code that you think may be able to be improved in some way, try codereview first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way to make this DRY?

```
$('#optionOne, #optionTwo').change(...);
```

That's called a [selector group](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping). None of the code in the change handler was specific to the element it was hooked to, so it was purely a matter of hooking it up to both elements.

---

Unrelated, but: This line is suspect:

```
queryBuilder.splice($(this).attr("id"));
```

`splice` expects at least two arguments: The index to start doing things at, and the number of elements to delete at that location (which might be 0, if you're then going to have more arguments which specify things to insert).

If your goal is to remove `$(this).attr("id")`'s value from the array, that won't do it. Instead:

```
var index = queryBuilder.indexOf($(this).attr("id"));
if (index != -1) {
    queryBuilder.splice(index, 1);
}
```

That finds it if it's there, and removes it.

---

Side note:

As squint said, `$(this).attr("id")` is just a long way to write `this.id`, and `$(this).prop("checked")` is just a long way to write `this.checked`. :-)

There's also never any reason to write `== true` when doing a comparison (there is, *rarely*, a reason to write `=== true`).

Finally, as `checked` can only ever be true or false, there's no need for the second `if`.

So:

```
$('#optionOne, #optionTwo').change(function() {
    var index;
    if (this.checked) {
        queryBuilder.push(this.id);
    } else {
        index = queryBuilder.indexOf(this.id);
        if (index != -1) {
            queryBuilder.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log(queryBuilder);
});
```

or slightly shorter:

```
$('#optionOne, #optionTwo').change(function() {
    var index;
    if (this.checked) {
        queryBuilder.push(this.id);
    } else if ((index = queryBuilder.indexOf(this.id)) != -1) {
        queryBuilder.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(queryBuilder);
});
```

---

**Over-analyzing it markedly**, I'll note that if we think there's any chance of it being in the array when the checkbox isn't checked, we should be a bit more defensive to avoid putting it in twice:

```
$('#optionOne, #optionTwo').change(function() {
    var index = queryBuilder.indexOf(this.id);
    if (this.checked && index == -1) {
        queryBuilder.push(this.id);
    } else if (!this.checked && index != -1) {
        queryBuilder.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(queryBuilder);
});
```

Okay, I'll stop now. :-)

---

Gah, one more thing: Some **very old** browsers don't have `Array#indexOf`, so if you need to support them, you'll need to add a shim or use jQuery's badly misnamed `$.inArray` instead. To use `inArray`, change `queryBuilder.indexOf(this.id)` to `$.inArray(queryBuilder, this.id)` (nothing else needs changing).

Comment: Simple, yet elegant! Thanks for the answer, I have tried this, but the whole array gets spliced upon toggling off!

Comment: @Rkhayat: That won't happen with the above if the code you've quoted that you say works actually does work.

Comment: You're right, I just checked and I had a bug with the splice it seems, thanks for the selector group answer! Will accept when possible.

Comment: @Rkhayat: I've added a note about the `splice` issue that may help.

Comment: Oh my! Can I accept this answer more than once?? :)

Comment: Nice improvements. He could also use jQuery's `.indexOf`. I think it's `$.inArray` or something like that.

Comment: Can you explain the "index != -1"? I am having trouble finding information on it for curiosity's sake.

Comment: @Rkhayat: Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf And squint is right, if there's a chance you're dealing with very old browsers, you can change `queryBuilder.indexOf(...)` to `$.inArray(queryBuilder, ...)`. It returns the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use of a common  class for common items is the simplest approach:

```
<input class="option-class" type="checkbox" id="optionTwo">
```

.

```
$('.option-class').change(/* your handler code */);
```

Although ID's are the easiest selector to target people get stuck on using them and in repeating components using classes allows DRY'ing the code a lot easier by targeting groups of elements instead of one at a time

Comment: Could take advantage of the existing class too (if consistent). `$(".checkbox-inline > [type=checkbox]")`